Greyed Out Version Delete button on Versions tab ( PowerApps)
Greyed Out Version Delete button on Versions tab ( PowerApps)
Hello All,
On a particular PowerApps app , I have an admin rights so can update or publish the app but cannot delete any of the versions.
The Delete button is disable even for the newer versions  ( not older than 6 months ) .
Is there any setting I can change the delete the older versions  on admin-centre or somewhere ?
I don't have this problem for other apps actually.

I want to delete the older versions easily, It makes me confused on version managements.

Are you primary owner of this app OR someone else created this app and shared with you as "Co-Owner"?

Hello Ganesh, someone else created and shared with me as Co Owner , Is it possible to set more than one primary owner ?

No, there can be only one primary owner. You can change primary owner using PowerShell: https://powerapps.microsoft.com/blog/updating-ownership-for-power-apps-apps?wt.mc_id=MVP_315224

Check with other person who created this app, if they can see the "Delete" option properly. If yes, ask them to delete or change the primary owner using above PowerShell method (there are other ways as well). Let me know if this approach works for you.

Thank you  so much Ganesh . last question , how can i find my user ID on Powerapp ? I dont have admin rights on Azure Portal and cannot see users there ,

You don't need admin rights on the Azure Portal to see the user ID. Go to https://portal.azure.com/ --> search for your email address in top search box --> click on your user name from search results --> you can get the user ID from URL at the end when you open your user account OR from "Overview" page (user ID is named as "Object ID" on the page).

It shows an error "Insufficient privileges to complete the operation". Error code 403 :(

Thank you mate, showing the ID on URL is an amazing idea. Appreciated , you have sorted my issue

Great, glad it worked for you. I have added this process in detail as an answer below.

As discussed in comments section above, I think you are unable to delete the previous versions of the canvas application because you are not primary owner of the application.
So, you have two options as given below:

Ask primary owner who created the app in first place to delete previous versions.
Replace primary owner with your user account.

For 2nd option, you can do it using Microsoft Power Apps PowerShell. For more details, check this Microsoft official article:
Updating ownership for Power Apps apps
PowerShell commands to use:
# Install required PowerShell modules
Install-Module -Name Microsoft.PowerApps.Administration.PowerShell
Install-Module -Name Microsoft.PowerApps.PowerShell – AllowClobber

# Run the Add-PowerAppsAccount cmtlet allowing you to add your account for Power Apps
Add-PowerAppsAccount

# Replace app owner
Set-AdminPowerAppOwner -AppName "<appId>" -EnvironmentName "<envId>" -AppOwner $Global:currentSession.userId


Thank you so much mate. It is clear for me now. Appriciated
